# WCF fail to return an existing object instance and works with new instances

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf

I'm writing a web service in WCF that returns a JSON in the response.

my issue is that when I'm returning an internal object instance (from a separate dll) the response is an error but when I'm creating a new instance of the same type locally the response includes all the data.

in my the service interface that function the returned type is that internal object.

some one knows how to explain?

Comment: Enable tracing to find the actual exception. Usually it's a circular reference which can't be serialized.

Comment: thanks! you were right, I needed to add a knownType attribute to one of my data contracts...
+1 for the help!